# Palabra reservada this como parametro

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public abstract class Notific<T extends Notifi> {

    public final void send() {
        NotificationEventPublisherFactory.createInstance().publishEvent(this);
    }

}
```

que es this? el metodo? la clase?

Comment: Un objecto de tipo `Notific`.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque desde la perspectiva del programador Java no permite el uso de punteros, la palabra reservada this es un puntero cuya dirección de memoria señala un objeto del tipo de la clase en donde la palabra se ha escrito.

Answer (score 1):

**this** no es un método o clase, this es una palabra reservada en java.¿Para que sirve, te comento brevemente:

This se utiliza   para indicar la referencia al objeto actual, se utiliza generalmente cuando existe ambigüedad entre atributos y parámetros métodos , es decir, cuando tiene el mismo nombre por ejemplo:

```
      public class Empleado {
             private int valor
        public Empleado(int valor){
              this.valor=valor
          } 
      }
```

Otro uso que le podemos dar es para invocar constructores de la misma clase, la invocación debe ir siempre en la misma linea por ejemplo:

```
    public class Empleado {
        private int valor;
    public Empleado(){
        this(125); //Este llama al segundo constructor
        } 
     }  
     public Empleado(int valor){
        this.valor=valor
      }
```

Ahora  cuando usamos this como argumento en un metodo, estamos enviando un objeto de la clase, por ejemplo:

```
public class Simuladores {

    private int atributo1;
    private int atributo2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    Simuladores obj= new Simuladores();
    obj.callThis();

    }
private void callThis(){
    setAtributo1(10);
    setAtributo2(5);
    testThis(this); // se envia un objeto del tipo Simuladores

}
    private void testThis(Simuladores aThis) {
     // aThis contiene los atributos de la clase

       int valor1 = aThis.atributo1;
       int valor2 = aThis.atributo2;
       System.out.println(valor1);
       System.out.println(valor2);

    }
```

> Corrección en definición.

Comment: "This se utiliza para invocar atributos y métodos dentro de la misma clase" error. `this` sirve para indicar la referencia al objeto actual. Por eso puede ser usado como parámetro en los métodos.

Answer (score 1):

La palabra reservada **'this'** se creó en principio para evitar conflictos entre variables globales y locales. Claro, la pregunta que se te vendrá a la cabeza es ¿y porqué no le pongo otro nombre distinto?

A la hora de desarrollar programas mas largos y extensos intervienen un montón de variables y buscar nombres distintos hará perder tiempo al programador y obviamente hacer mas costosa la rutinaria tarea de seguir el código.

*"la referencia **this** siempre apunta al objeto sobre el que se ejecuta un metodo."*

Date cuenta que ***this*** no apunta a variables, si no a objetos, es decir que si en tu clase no tuvieras atributos y usarás **this**, no sucedería nada, compilaría igual. Cuando haces **this**, accedes a las variables del objeto y no a las variables locales de sus métodos.

Por eso es importante saber que, si invocas **this** desde un método estático *(que no necesita instanciar una clase para poder usarse)* **this** no funcionará porque no tendrá a ningún objeto que apuntar.

Por lo que en tu caso, **this** apuntará a un objeto de la clase **NotificationEventPublisherFactory**.

Answer (score 1):

La palabra `this` es una autoreferencia. La palabra `this` permite en bloques de código de referirse al objeto actual. En un método se refiere al objeto a que se llama el método. Un ejemplo:

```
Notific n = new Notific();
// lamada a send() de n
n.send();
// en el caso de tu objeto equivalente a:                       v aquí la referencia
NotificationEventPublisherFactory.createInstance().publishEvent(n);
```

También se puede usar `this` para llamar a otros constructores dentro de un constructor, o para desambiguar entre un campo y una variable local:

```
`public clase MiClase{

     int valor=0;

     public MiClase(int valor){
         // asignar la variable local al campo del mismo nombre:
         this.valor=valor;
     }

     public MiClase(){
         // el constructor sin valor asume un valor inicial de 100 por defecto:
         this(100); 
     }
 }
```

En este caso ´new MiClase()`es equivalente a`new MiClase(100)`.

Comment: sus respuestas se contradicen

Comment: Que se contradice con que?

Comment: las respuestas de ti con voiser

Comment: Entonces una de la respuestas esta falso, o una de las respuestas esta malentendido. Mi respuesta enfoca al contexto que diste en tu pregunta. La respuesta de voiser empieza con los otros usos de `this`, dejando el uso en tu contexto al fin. Puede ser eso que llega al malentendido?